# Robospice nullpointerexception when trying to POST

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, robospice

I am trying to make a POST request by ROBOSPICE and I get a `NullpointerException`:

```
 public String loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {

    return getRestTemplate().getForObject(url, String.class);
}
```

Here is the exact Error occurring in `return` line

> An exception occurred during request network execution :null
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: it would be kind of you to answer instead of voting down

Comment: Seems as though `getRestTemplate()` returns `null`. Have you tried to debug and check if this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround your request with a try-catch block.

```
try{
    return getRestTemplate().getForObject(url, String.class);
}catch(RestTemplateException e){
    Log.d("appError", e.getMessage());
}
```

This error is probably because you're getting a null response. Try verifying first what you're getting as response.